# how can i find a not timestamp data in dataframe python?

Tags: python, dataframe, timestamp

Here is the timestamp column:

```
TIME
2018-03-02 11:57:37
2018-03-12 10:36:16
2018-03-29 12:02:21
2018-03-23 16:37:08
2018-03-09 22:22:28
         .
         .
```

And I tried merge and faced the following error.

```
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'datetime.datetime' and 'int'
```

So I tried to find a column with a different data type like under code, but it didn't worked.

```
for i in range(len(ds)):
    if type(ds['TIME'].loc[i]) != type(ds['TIME'].loc[1]) : 
        ds = ds.drop(i)
# type(ds['TIME'].loc[1]) was confirmed that it was a timestamp type
```

how can i solve this problem?

I would be grateful if you give me some good advice.

this is what i try.

```
raw_data = pd.merge_ordered(ds,ds2)
#ds2 is similar data like ds
```

+I think it might be a parse problem in db.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you need create default index for prevent duplicated by [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) and then call [`drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.drop_duplicates.html):

```
ds['TIME'].reset_index(drop=True).drop_duplicates()
```

If possible multiple columns:

```
ds.reset_index(drop=True).drop_duplicates(subset=['TIME'])
```

Comment: Thank you for giving me a good comparison. Still, the errors that appear above are not resolved. Is there a way to resolve this error?

Comment: i also didn't worked. and i check all data type using type(), all data is same(<class 'pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp'>). it so hard to solve it     ㅜㅜ

Comment: in my real data it has not duplicate date(check ds.drop_duplicate()). TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'datetime.datetime' and 'int' <--Does this error occur when the same data exists?

Comment: @송준석 - Do youi think `ds['TIME'].drop_duplicates()` ? If failed, try `ds['TIME'].reset_index(drop=True).drop_duplicates()`

Comment: i think it didn't worked. if you  give your email, i sen real data. 
Looking at the actual data, the problem seems to be clearer.

Comment: @송준석 - Sure, check my profile - only run code for my email

Comment: oh , i'm really sorry. 
The problem was that the string in the column next to time was a problem.It was an error that occurred when the other column was not a merge because it had the two type of data( string and integer type.)It is my fault that I have not confirmed anything minor. please forgive me.

Comment: @송준석 - yes, it should be problem if need `merge` - need same types of data.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use built-in type() function.
I don't know if this is a correct way, but is simple:

```
if 'datetime' in str(type(ds)):
    print('Is a datetime format')
```

Comment: in case of my data, str(type(ds)) 's result is  "<class 'pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp'>" so i use upper code using 'timestamps' but it also didn't worked